# Average with parametric cell in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm desperately looking for a way to write a function like this:

```
=SUM(A1:CELL(B1))/COUNT(A1:CELL(B1))
```

where CELL(B1) contains a text, for example "A37".

In this way, I can do the average only in the cell that I want consider for now.
I now seems a strange request, because I could just change directly the formula, but in my case I have to use this value "A37" in a lot of formulas, and so I'm looking for a way to use **parametric cell**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your requirement:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("a1:"&B1))/COUNT(INDIRECT("a1:"&B1))
```

is possible, but does not seem advisable.